# Which ports does Secure Gateway Client use?

Tags: ibm-cloud, secure-gateway

I plan to set the Secure Gateway Client at DMZ at on-premise environment, so I need to open Outbound ports for SG Client to connect to SG on Bluemix. The following question is similar to my question, but the answer doesn't show the needed ports.

**For the Bluemix Secure Gateway service, how does the data center's network need to be configured?**
[For the Bluemix Secure Gateway service, how does the data center's network need to be configured?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30126987/for-the-bluemix-secure-gateway-service-how-does-the-data-centers-network-need)

The following Bluemix Doc shows Outbound 443 is needed.

https://www.ng.bluemix.net/docs/troubleshoot/SecureGateway/ts_index-gentopic1.html#ts_sg_006

**What are the best practices for running the Secure Gateway client?**
*Before you install the Docker client into your environment, ensure that both the internet and your on-premises assets are accessible and all host names are resolvable by a DNS. The client uses outbound port 443 to connect to the IBM Bluemix environment, normally this port is open since its secure. Ensure you check or modify additional firewall and IP Table rules that might apply.*

But, the tcpdump, which I got when I executed "docker run -it ibmcom/secure-gateway-client XXXX", showed that SG Client used Outbound 443 and 9000. Is it collect that all ports SG Client uses are Outbound 443 and 9000 ?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Correct, if you are closing down both outbound and inbound ports using your firewall, then for outbound allow ports 443/9000.  So your initial assertion is correct.